# Encoding hell with R's `read.` functions

Tags: r, csv, encoding, character-encoding, write.table

Long story short, i have this `data.csv` file that i created by using `read.xls` and `write.csv`, `read.table` and `write.table` in that order.

Problem is that even though structure seems fairly good and ready to be optimized i can't set the encoding to `encoding = "UTF-8"` or `fileEncode = "UTF-8"`.

Whenever i try to, i get various errors like `encoding = "UTF-8" unused argument`, `no valid input`, etc. Example is reproducible so feel free to test that (just copy paste into an .csv file and open in excel or whatever).
So here is a small portion of `data.csv` contents that i would be more than happy to convert.

```
"V1 ""V2""  ""V3"""                     
"1  NA  """ \"V1\"  \"V2\"  \"V3\"  \"V4\"  \"V5\"  \"V6\"
"2  1   """ NA  \"Ξ™Ξ‘ΞΞΞ¥Ξ‘Ξ΅Ξ™ΞΞ£\"   NA  \"1 017.90\"    NA
"3  2   """ NA  \"Ξ¦Ξ•Ξ’Ξ΅ΞΞ¥Ξ‘Ξ΅Ξ™ΞΞ£\"    NA  \"1 016.45\"    NA
"4  3   """ NA  \"ΞΞ‘Ξ΅Ξ¤Ξ™ΞΞ£\"    NA  \"1 015.84\"    NA
"5  4   """ NA  "\""Ξ‘Ξ""   "" Ξ΅Ξ™Ξ›Ξ™ΞΞ£\"""  NA  \"1 013.73\"    NA
"6  5   """ NA  \"ΞΞ‘Ξ™ΞΞ£\"    NA  \"1 014.15\"    NA
"7  6   """ NA  \"Ξ™ΞΞ¥ΞΞ™ΞΞ£\" NA  \"1 013.71\"    NA
"8  7   """ NA  \"Ξ™ΞΞ¥Ξ›Ξ™ΞΞ£\"    NA  \"1 012.31\"    NA
"9  8   """ NA  \"Ξ‘Ξ¥Ξ“ΞΞ¥Ξ£Ξ¤ΞΞ£\"    NA  \"1 012.68\"    NA
"10 9   """ NA  "\""Ξ£Ξ•Ξ"" "" Ξ¤Ξ•ΞΞ’Ξ΅Ξ™ΞΞ£\"""   NA  \"1 015.49\"    NA
"11 10  """ NA  \"ΞΞΞ¤Ξ©Ξ’Ξ΅Ξ™ΞΞ£\" NA  \"1 017.59\"    NA
"12 11  """ NA  \"ΞΞΞ•ΞΞ’Ξ΅Ξ™ΞΞ£\"  NA  \"1 017.88\"    NA
"13 12  """ NA  \"Ξ”Ξ•ΞΞ•ΞΞ’Ξ΅Ξ™ΞΞ£\"   NA  \"1 017.22\"    NA
"14 13  """ NA  \"Ξ•Ξ¤ΞΞ£\" NA  \"1 015.41\"    NA
"15 14  """ NA  \"7/3/2014\"    NA  \"\"    NA  NA
```

Note that during first `read.xls` (`gdata` package) i get `wide character` warning from perls `xls2csv.pl` script

and later on `Warning messages:
1: In write.table(b, "data.csv", sep = "\t", append = TRUE) :
  appending column names to file` from R.

I think i might have screwed `sep` argument also.

Anyway i would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: try `fread` in the `data.table` package, that is supposed to take care of the tedious bit for you.

Comment: You could try XLConnect

Comment: @KarlForner I did and things went pretty bad with it too. Worse than with `gdata`. Anyway i found a workaround to solve the issue.. thanks btw

Comment: @user1834437 : so what's your workaround? Please post it as a brief answer for our benefit.